# Is it possible to distinguish between cyclohexanol and cyclohex-2-en-1-ol with simple chemical test?

Tags: organic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, alcohols

Primary, secondary and tertiary alcohols can easily be distinguished by using reagent tests such as:

- The triiodomethane test for $\ce{R-CH(CH3)OH}$ alcohols.
- Lucas' reagent to distinguish between three alcohol groups.
- A combination of reagents to distinguish between three alcohols. For example, dichromate to distinguish between tertiary and primary/secondary alcohols and subsequently Fehling's solution to distinguish between primary and secondary alcohols.

Would it be possible to distinguish between two secondary alcohols? For example, between cyclohexanol (**1**) and cyclohex-2-en-1-ol (**2**) using simple chemical tests?

[image: 1: cyclohexanol; 2: cyclohex-2-en-1-ol]

Comment: There are reagents like MnO2 which will selectively oxidise allylic alcohols, and can therefore act as a basis for chemically differentiating the above two compounds. I'm not sure that's what you are looking for, though? Are you looking for something that can be done quickly in a test tube in a high school-ish lab?

Comment: An alternate approach for this specific case would be Br2 reaction with the alkene

Comment: Yes, it is possible to distinguish.

Comment: Yes. Try [Br2 in CCl4/KMnO4 in either acidic or alkaline medium/HBr](https://people.uwplatt.edu/~sundin/354-1/5411001d.htm)